# Using Bamboo CLI from Command Prompt

Tags: command-line-interface, bamboo

I am trying to fetch the plan details of a `Bamboo Project` using Bamboo CLI. I downloaded the `Bobswift CLI`and a `jar` file was downloaded. i opened command prompt in the folder that had this `jar` file and i ran the command `bamboo --action getProjectList`. But i am getting an error as `'bamboo' not recognized as an internal command`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Windows you need to run the following command in the command prompt : "bamboo.bat --action getProjectList"

If you are using linux or OSx run the following in the terminal "./bamboo.sh --action getProjectList"

Comment: Do we need to open command prompt at bamboo.bat file location?

Comment: Yes unless you add that bat to the path